# PHP won't show any errors

Tags: php, error-reporting

Here is my code:

```
echo 'foo';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo 'this line doesnt end in a semi colon'

echo 'i should get an error here';
```

When I run this I get no error.

Not sure how this can be?

Comment: Am I the only person who prefers to just `tail -f` the error log? :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson depends on the site state. for developnemt I prefer on-screen

Comment: `I get no error. ` means `I get all 3 lines printed` or `I get a blank screen`?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I get a blank screen. I added `php_flag dislay errors 1`. Which at first didn't work. Then I added `<Directory "/var/www/aquaplatinum">Order allow,deny Allow from all AllowOverride All </Directory>` To my apache2.conf file and restarted apache and now the errors are showing.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yeah even for development i prefer the log... This is because I like `E_ALL|E_STRICT` but i dont want warning ouput fudging the xhtml. Plus, im normally running `tail` directly in an Eclipse as an external tool :-)

Comment: @John you could add just `AllowOverride All` there and then use .htaccess which is usually more handy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Do note though that if you do this in the file that has the syntax error, it won't work, as it'll never get executed then. You can also set this true in php.ini (not recommended for production servers), or if you use Apache, in .htaccess with:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

Comment: so php_flag display_errors 1 should show all errors allways? (cause its not my case)

Comment: No, it only tells that errors are displayed at all. The `error_reporting` configuration value determines what errors are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

error_reporting directive won't help you to show error messages on-screen. It's responsible for *which* error to show, not *where*.

if your PHP runs as Apache module (most likely it does) add the following line into `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value display_errors 1
```

when you switch to production, change it to

```
php_value display_errors 0
php_value log_errors 1
```

and watch them it in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any kind of shutdown hooks, error-handling functions or global exception catchers running?

Syntax errors can be quirky in large frameworks :)